# how to identify the week from current date in java

Tags: java, date

I want to identity the whole week date(From Sunday To Saturday)  using current date in java.

For Example: Today is Tuesday - it means I need dates for Tuesday, Monday and Sunday.

If current day is Wednesday - then I need dates from Sunday to  Wednesday.

How to achieve this logic in java?

I'm able to get the start of week from current date, but I don't know how to get the remaining day date from Week start date.  Is there any java utility available for this?

Comment: so add one day to your start week date till the day you want

Comment: Have a look at `Calendar`, `setWeekDate()`, `getFirstDayOfWeek()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*For reference, the current date used to formulate the output was Wednesday, 22nd July, 2015 (22/07/2015)*

## Java 8

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate sunday = ld.minusDays(ld.getDayOfWeek().getValue());
LocalDate tommorrow = ld.plusDays(1);
LocalDate date = sunday;
while (date.isBefore(tommorrow)) {
    System.out.println(date);
    date = date.plusDays(1);
}
```

Prints

```
2015-07-19
2015-07-20
2015-07-21
2015-07-22
```

**As an alternative**

(Which will basically work for all the other mentioned APIs) you could simply walk backwards from today...

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
do {
    System.out.println(date);
    date = date.minusDays(1);
} while (date.getDayOfWeek() != DayOfWeek.SATURDAY);
```

Prints

```
2015-07-22
2015-07-21
2015-07-20
2015-07-19
```

## JodaTime

```
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate sunday = now.minusDays(5).withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY);
LocalDate tommorrow = now.plusDays(1);
LocalDate date = sunday;
while (date.isBefore(tommorrow)) {
    System.out.println(date);
    date = date.plusDays(1);
}
```

Prints

```
2015-07-19
2015-07-20
2015-07-21
2015-07-22
```

## Calendar

As a last resort.  Remember though, `Calendar` carries time information, so using `before`, `after` and `equals` may not always do what you think they should...

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);

Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

while (cal.before(today)) {
    System.out.println(cal.getTime());
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
```

Prints

```
Sun Jul 19 15:01:49 EST 2015
Mon Jul 20 15:01:49 EST 2015
Tue Jul 21 15:01:49 EST 2015
Wed Jul 22 15:01:49 EST 2015
```

Comment: Never realized one could loop `LocalDate`. That's pretty cool.

Comment: @EddieB It's a left over idea of the old `Calendar` days ;)

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy using Java 8. However, note, the iso-8601 standard represents `Monday` as the first day of the week... [See the JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html)... so to implement your requirements you simply find `Monday` as the base case...

> DayOfWeek is an enum representing the 7 days of the week - Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday and Sunday.
>
> In addition to the textual enum name, each day-of-week has an int value. The int value follows the ISO-8601 standard, from 1 (Monday) to 7 (Sunday). It is recommended that applications use the enum rather than the int value to ensure code clarity.

```
/**
* @author Edward Beckett :: <Edward@EdwardBeckett.com>
* @since :: 7/22/2015
*/
public class WeekOfToday{

public static void main( String[] args ) {

    Integer dayOfWeek = LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek().compareTo( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ;
    LocalDate startOfWeek =  LocalDate.now().minusDays( dayOfWeek );
    LocalDate endOfWeek = LocalDate.now().plusDays( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY.getValue() - dayOfWeek - 1 );
    }
}
```

> output

```
Start of Week : 2015-07-20
End of Week : 2015-07-26
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to identity the whole week date(From Sunday To Saturday) using current date in java.

This should solve your problem, you can further modify according to your situation.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
System.out.println("Date " + c.getTime());
c.add(Calendar.DATE, +1);
System.out.println(c.getTime());
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I think you will need a `c.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY)`, otherwise `c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY)` will advance the date in locales where Sunday is not the first day of the week.

Comment: Yes you are correct, in that case we need to set the first day if the situation demands. But as the user has explicitly mentioned about `Sunday` to `CurrentDayOfWeek`. I did that.